# how to enforce redux action only dispatch once?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am wondering how to flag redux action not dispatch the second time.

```
let triggerOnce = false;

export function populateStore() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    if (triggerOnce) return;

    dispatch({
      type: ReviewActions.UPDATE_REVIEW_STATE,
      data: review,
    });

    triggerOnce = true;
  };
}
```

as you can see right now i am using an external variable to flag... which is not that great. wondering if there is a better way. Thanks heaps for any suggestion

Comment: What dispatches `populateStore`? `triggerOnce` should probably be stored in state so it can be de/serialized. Whatever calls `populateStore` could check this flag before dispatching.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue that's a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used lodash `once()` else you can implement a closure with flag.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#once

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure of your context so I apologize if I'm mistaken. I would attempt to find a way to only call the action once rather than set a flag in the global scope. If that's not desirable, you could set a flag in your reducer that is set to `true` once it's been populated.

```
const initialState = {
   hasBeenSet: false,
   ...restOfState,
}

const events = {
  [UPDATE_REVIEW_STATE]: (state) => {
     const { hasBeenSet } = state;

     return hasBeenSet ? state : { ...state, hasBeenSet: true };
  },
};
```

I hope that helps!